# Aggregate by group and subgroups with result in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with groups, sub groups, and sub groups of the sub groups. I want to aggregate by the sum, like shown below:

```
grp,   sub_group, sub_sub_group, sum
grp-A,                           10
       sub-A,                     6
                  sub_sub_A       3
                  sub_sub_B       3
       sub-B,                     4
                  sub_sub_A       4
```

So the sum for `grp-A` is achieved from `sub-A` and `sub-B` (6+4) , which is the sum of their own respective sub groups. How can I achieve this with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do you have sample source data?

Comment: Have you considered 'GROUP BY ROLLUP (grp, sub_group);?

Comment: @r2evans unfortunately not, but after @tinaymu's comment I checked `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, and it seems to be provide what I'm looking for. Here's a sql fiddle I tried: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3xH4AWrSqcbfjAKQTyNWc/0

Answer (score 1):

The essential issue here is that the `sum` column has different meaning for different rows.  The various meanings are related, to be sure, but not enough so for the query to be particularly clean.  The best I can come up with is to perform each level of aggregation via its own  query, combine the result sets, and then sort them into the wanted order.  This is one way that might look:

```sql
with fine_agg as (
  select grp, sub_group, sub_sub_group, sum(datum) as datum
  from base_table
  group by grp, sub_group, sub_sub_group
), mid_agg as (
  select grp, sub_group, NULL as sub_sub_group, sum(datum) as datum
  from fine_agg
  group by grp, sub_group
), coarse_agg as (
  select grp, NULL as sub_group, NULL as sub_sub_group, sum(datum) as datum
  from mid_agg
  group by grp
), all_agg as (
  select * from fine_agg
  union all
  select * from mid_agg
  union all
  select * from all_agg
)
select grp, sub_group, sub_sub_group, datum as "sum"
from all_agg
order by grp, sub_group nulls first, sub_sub_group nulls first
```

If you don't care about the order of the rows then you could unroll one level of that, using the union query as the top-level one.

Note well that the results will be ambiguous if `base_table.sub_group` or `base_table.sub_sub_group` contain any nulls.

Comment: thanks, upvoted! @tinazmu commented about `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, and I looked into it, and it seems to have the same result. I think using `GROUP BY ROLLUP` is more performant in this case

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the late reply, but I went over the query again and the `order by` is not fully correct. You can check this db fiddle I made: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3xH4AWrSqcbfjAKQTyNWc/0 
The sorting is done alphabetically, so the number 400 appears below the 300. Do you know how the sorting can be fixed?

Comment: @Snow, the DBMS will choose between lexicographic and numeric ordering based on the data type of the sort key.  Your fiddle does not suggest differently.  In fact, your fiddle does not serve to test that question, because the primary and secondary sort columns fully establish the order of the result rows.  The only numeric column -- the tertiary one -- is not needed to establish the relative order of any pairs of rows in the included test data.

Comment: ... or *any* set of test data, for that matter, because the first two sort columns are also the full set of grouping columns.